# Android background

Tags: android, background

In my app I used a background image - 480x800, size - 464kb, but when I trying to run it in emulators with api <15 I had a OOM errors, but if I run it without background all works well. Maybe anyone has some solutions of this? Or some recomendation to work with background?

Comment: put the image in `drawable-xhdpi`

Comment: it may depend on the way you load it, can you post the code for all the manipulations you do on the image?

Comment: Tecigo, only this     android:background="@drawable/image_bg"

Comment: use smaller background images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ram kiran said

use `drawable-xhdpi` for keeping large size images.

for coming to images with the size `480x800` have different look in portrait and landscape,

so its better to use

```
  drawable-port-xhdpi for portable images
```

(and use )

```
 drawable-land-xhdpi for landscape image
```

Read [thsis](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more clarification